# Is is possible to configure multiple git repositories in Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I would like to read some configurations from multiple git repositories, something like:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: base, app1, app2
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        base:
          uri: http://${GIT_HOST}/base/base.git
          username: ${GIT_USERNAME}
          password: ${GIT_PASSWORD}
        app1:
          uri: http://${GIT_HOST}/group1/app1.git
          username: ${GIT_USERNAME}
          password: ${GIT_PASSWORD}
        app2:
          uri: http://${GIT_HOST}/group2/app2.git
          username: ${GIT_USERNAME}
          password: ${GIT_PASSWORD}
```

At startup I see the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository
```

The [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_composite_environment_repositories) shows an example using two different repos, git and svn. Can't we use multiple repos of the same kind?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the link of document you said, the `svn` and `git` after `server` is the type, not profile. So you cannot use base, app1, app2.
But in your case, I think you can use this kind of config: [document link](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_git_backend).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://git/common/config-repo.git
          repos:
            team-a:
                pattern: team-a-*
                cloneOnStart: true
                uri: http://git/team-a/config-repo.git
            team-b:
                pattern: team-b-*
                cloneOnStart: false
                uri: http://git/team-b/config-repo.git
            team-c:
                pattern: team-c-*
                uri: http://git/team-a/config-repo.git
```